# Can one project have multiple backlogs in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

We have tried to find out how to set up multiple (portfolio level) backlogs for a single project in Azure Devops? I know that this is possible in JIRA, but is this possible in Azure? Or is the only possibility to establish separate projects and then have independent backlogs?

The team which is involved in the project is having 2 separate sub-projects (which are partly overlapping, but not much). It would be convenient to have these separate backlogs within this one project, but ofc, if it's not possible, then it isn't. Any experience?

Comment: Hi, Ninza. What about the Roberto's answer? Does his answer could help you solve the puzzle? Please [mark the correct answer as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you can do it configuring differents areas in Azure DevOps.

And when you'll create your backlog, you can associate it to the correct area and separate both teams.

Go to your Project Settings --> Project Configuration --> Areas
[image: Project Configuration]

Comment: Thanks Roberto! I tried setting up these areas (and managed to do so), but as there already is a team and a backlog up&running, DevOps won't let me change the composition of the team for the areas. This might be due to my credentials as well, maybe mine are not powerful enough.

I think we are going to set up an additional project, as this area approach seems kinda arduous. I think what you proposed could work, but maybe it would be easier to start with a fresh backlog and team settings (not the case atm).

Comment: If you have workitems running already it's not a problem as well, you can move then to different areas path and separate both teams.

Please try on this Lab those concepts: 

https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/agile/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple backlogs with a single team. What I do is create a second team based on the product name and have the same team members. I then create a different sub-area and then you can have a backlog per product that look at those sub-areas. Then for your "real" team they have a backlog that can roll up the sub-areas.